# Android State Machine

Tags: class, android-intent, android-activity, android

I write an Android application. I have a lot of Activities in my application with a large number of transitions between Activities. I decided to realize a state machine, which will switch my activities.

I hoped to realize a State Machine in  my Application class or its subclass, but I can't start any Activity from it.

```
public class MainAppClass extends Application {}
```

the code like this is failing:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this.MyActivity, Screen2Activity.class);
StartActivity(intent);
```

Maybe, is it unreal? Are there other methods for such tasks?
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  The application class is automatically generated (after you add it to the manifest) when you launch your main activity... you don't need to launch an activity from the application class (nor do I believe you should).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another question: *Why are you trying to start an activity from a subclass of `Application`?*

Read this (from the documentation) and you'll see why what you are trying to do doesn't make any sense.

> The `Application` class is the base class for those who need to maintain global application state. There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register broadcast receivers), the function to retrieve it can be given a `Context` which internally uses `Context.getApplicationContext()` when first constructing the singleton.

If you edit your original post, clarifying why you are trying to do this, perhaps I can point you to a more suitable means of launching your `Screen2Activity`.